# Azure pipeline self-hosted agent, how to see attached USB devices?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

*I'd like to find out how we can access our attached USB device from inside of an azure pipelines self-hosted job.*

I am setting up hardware-in-the-loop testing with Azure Pipelines.

We have our USB device attached to a Windows 10 computer, running a self-hosted agent.

When manually running our tests locally, our software is able to see & communicate with the attached USB device.
When running the same tests though azure pipelines, the USB device is not detected.

The self-hosted runner is using the local user account, the same login we're using for manual testing.

The easiest way we've been able to detect the problem is with this `wmic` command:

```
wmic path CIM_LogicalDevice where "Description like 'Saleae%'" get /value
```

When run manually from `cmd`, it returns the details of our connected USB device.

However, when run from azure pipelines, it returns the message `No Instance(s) Available.`, indicating that the device isn't connected.

Relevant pipelines yaml:

```
jobs:
- job: performance
  pool:
    name: Default
  steps:
    - script: |
        wmic path CIM_LogicalDevice where "Description like 'Saleae%'" get /value
```

Comment: 1. Make sure the agent used in your pipeline is the same one that connects to the USB device. (If more than one agents in Default pool. Azure Devops will pick one of them randomly) 2. Try configuring a self-agent in Service mode which is strongly recommended and run the pipeline again. Feel free to let me know if that make any difference.

Comment: Not exactly a solution, but this "just worked" with a GitHub action self hosted runner running as NOT a service. Since GitHub actions just use Azure pipelines under the hood, it's likely that this might have been fixed for Azure Pipelines self-hosted runners too.